# secure access to external web API .NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have two web APIs applications developed in .Net core. I need to import Json data from the second application to the first. However,I have a security issue. I need to secure the access to the external API. How should I securely  manage the connection between these two APIs.
For example, I need to secure the access to the URL in the code bellow => securely access to the covid API without another authentication.

PS: I'm using JWT token authentication in both applications

Best regards.

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
      string url = string.Format("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api");
      var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
    
      string responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CovidResult>(responseAsString);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"? You're already using HTTPS, you should also add some authentication or token to prove who's accesing. What are you looking for? What are you trying to defend against?

Comment: Also, never use `Task.Result` as it leads to deadlocks. Use `await` instead, just like you're reading the result string.

Comment: @Alejandro thank you for your reply, I'm looking for authentcating external use of the covid API. How to prove how's accessing from the first to the second application. Users from the first application are authenticated using jwt. However, if I allow only authentcated members of the second application  to access to the covid API, users from the first API will be not allowed to access

Comment: because you own 2 apps on the server, so this is possible by introducing the so-called *client id* or *app id* and *client secret* or *app token*. So that's kind of credentials used to authenticate the app (not user). It's much like how Google, FB, ... manage their applications created by developers which consume the services they provide.

Comment: Do you have an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both APIs are protected by the same accessToken, then you can read the authorization header from the first request and pass it to the second request.
Something like this to read the header:

```
var authHeader = context.Request.Headers.Get("Authorization");
```

You should end up with authHeader equal to "Bearer ey...(a bunch of base64)"

Then add the auth header to the client:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage() {
RequestUri = new Uri("http://https://covid19.mathdro.id/api"),
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
};

...

request.Headers.Authorization.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue(authHeader));
var task = client.SendAsync(request)
```

Comment: So, I need to add the same authentication token to  the request from my first APP in order to prove authenticty to acccess to the external covid API.? Which is the result of the authHeader variable?

Comment: It is difficult to determine your needs without knowing your configuration.  Are both api's configured to use Oauth2 with jwt?  If both are protected by the same tokens, then you can just pass that token to the next request.  If this is what you need, then my sample should be possible. Just keep in mind this only contains your access token and those expire. Your initial client is likely handing the silent refresh of your access token.  This likely won't be an issue if the request is handled quickly, but if you require the token to run a long process, it could fail.

Comment: Both of my APIs use Oauth2 with jwt but not the same token. Is the authHeader the token to access to the second API? and how to generate it ?

Comment: What is providing authentication? Google? Azure? Etc? The method to configure can vary. But generally, your token is literally the portion of the Authorization header after the text “Bearer”. If you have two separate “registrations” you need to allow the first one to access the scope of the second one, then you’ll be able to use the same token. Otherwise no it will not work.

Comment: King Kong's answer is what you should do IMO.  Just secure the second API with application credentials since you own it. Then have api 1 login to api 2 with those credentials.  I'm sure you have a good reason for api 2, but can you just put the code api 2 performs into api 1?